# Detecting collision with walls (is this a good solution?)

Tags: java, collision-detection

I'm trying to make the collision smooth (it must open the animation, but not move the character).

I've implemented 'fake positions':

- int step = 20;
- fake_left_x = x-step;
- fake_right_x = x+step;
- fake_up_y = y+step;
- fake_down_y = y-step;

While updating player position, I'm checking if fake positions are out of the screen. If yes - nothing happens.

Is this a good solution? What do you think?

Comment: The information you have provided is not enough for anybody to help provide a solution for you. Describe the variable names you have mentioned. Have you tried the solution you mention in your question? Does it work? What else have you tried? What library are you using?

Comment: Your solution is effectively a set of sensors ([like in this drawing](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qS5rN.png)) that tell you whether they're touching something. Your code seems to be just fine for implementing that.

Comment: One might add that, for big `step` sizes, odd effects may occur - namely, that the player runs towards a wall, and then simply *stops* even if it does not touch the wall yet. Computing the "time of impact" (and moving only as far as possible until he touches the wall) is not sooo difficult, you might want to consider it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a more typical way:

```
if (hit key left)
{
    animation.play();
    targetPosition.x = x - step; //this is where we propose to move to
}

//... repeat as above for right, up, down

//now only move if it's a valid move
//x axis:
if (targetPosition.x >= 0 && targetLocation < xPositionsCount) //target position is valid
{
    newPlayerPosition = targetPosition; //or gradually move move the sprite to target
}

//...y axis is similar to x axis
```